# How to convert mbtiles to .osm.pbf

Tags: qt, mbtiles, osm.pbf

I'm writing a Qt application that is supposed to show a geo-map of a specific geographical region in one of its views on top of which I need to be able to draw various other graphical elements.

The requirements are that all the map-tiles must be pre-downloaded for off-line use as during the use of the application there will be no internet connection.

After lengthy search for a suitable library that I could link into my Qt project that would support my needs (off-line tile loading, rendering and painting the map in Qt framework, non-QML only C++ integration) I thought [libOsmScout](http://libosmscout.sourceforge.net) would do the job.

However, I have managed to download **.mbtiles** files for my region from [OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/planet) just to realise that libOsmScout cannot natively work with .mbtiles.
The library can only work (indirectly after "import") with **.osm.pbf** files.
(http://libosmscout.sourceforge.net/tutorials/importing/)

I've searched extensively the web but all the results were pointing to conversion procedures in the opposite direction, i.e. into the .mbtiles.

So my question is: is it possible to convert **.mbtiles** files to **.osm.pbf** format so I can then [import](http://libosmscout.sourceforge.net/tutorials/importing/) it into libOsmScout compatible internal set of files?
If it is possible, what the process?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can just download osm.pbf files directly from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/.  

osm.pbf is one of the "native" format for OSM data, that's why everything is converting away from it.  https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html#examples) to convert to `pbf` format.

```
 ogr2ogr -f MVT output_dir_name input.mbtiles -dsco MAXZOOM=2
```

This will create a directory structure with each zoom level having a directory and `pbf` file named according to the tile position.

Or

using this tool called [MBUtil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil).

There are some steps which you can follow from the github repo.
After that, you can then use the following command to convert to directory structure with each tile in `pbf` format.

```
mb-util input.mbtiles output_dir_name image_format=pbf
```

where `tiles` is the directory name you want

Comment: This did not work for me.
Well it created all the .pbf files, but if I check them with osmium-tool fileinfo, I receive this error: "PBF error: invalid BlobHeader size (> max_blob_header_size)" and I can't find any nodes using libosmium.

With both ogr2ogr and mbutil.
(Also ogr2ogr creates significantly larger files than MBUtil)